# How to find coordinates of a chord given one point on a circle

Tags: math, geometry

**Update**

I do not think this question is off topic.
The solution provided is what I was looking for and it is a programming solution.

================

I want to know how can I find the coordinates of equal chords from the same point on the circle.
As shown in the image below, I will like to choose a random point on a circle and a random chord angle (in the example its 110 degrees).

I will know the radius (r) of the circle and one randomly selected point (A) on a circle.
Based on this data, I would like to know how can I draw two equal chords from this point (AB and AC) where AB = AC.

[image]

Comment: you mean where the length of AB equals the length of AC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, and not about programming.

Comment: How is it not about programming? The solution I was looking for was provided to me by MBo and it is a programming solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let you have circle center xc, yc, radius R.

At first choose random angle in range 0..2*Pi

```
aangle = random(2*Pi)
```

Then A coordinates are

```
ax = xc + R * Cos(aangle)
ay = yc + R * Sin(aangle)
```

Now choose random (or you need specific value?) chord angle in needed range and get B, C coordinates

```
changle = random(3 * Pi / 4) 
bx = xc + R * Cos(aangle + changle)
cx = xc + R * Cos(aangle - changle) // note subtraction
and similar for Y-coordinates
```

If you have A coordinates, you can also rotate them around center

```
bx = xc + (ax - xc) * Cos(changle) - (ay - yc) * Sin(changle) 
and so on
```

Comment: Thanks MBo for your solution. It gets me pretty close. In your solution, did you consider "changle" to be the angle A(center)B or angle BAC.

Comment: changle  (chord angle) is angle from A to B and from A to C,  `changle = AB = AC = 1/2 BAC`

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Appreciate your help :)